# Submitted application crash at launch

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

I have updated my app (Baby Songs) today by adding some lullabies.
When I tested my app on the device, everything worked great. 
But when I download the app from the store (https://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/baby-songs/3c30a535-6483-410f-9fc1-a2248a77f9b0) the app crash at launch.

Can give me some track to understand this crash ?

I have try to rollback to previous commit, and the application still crash...

When I install the .xap manually (with wp power tool), everything works...

I have submit .xap file on my own account on beta (my account use the old dashboard, don't know why) And there is no crashs.

For me, it's definitively a problem with the new dashboard.

Comment: Have you changed any database schema at all? Do you see the crash from a clean install, or only when updating? Do you have the development version installed on the phone as well?

Comment: My app does not contain any database. I have try both : update and clean install, with and without development version installed

Comment: you can check in the windowsphone dev center (where you uploaded the app) for crash logs. It shows somewhere under reports i think.

Comment: Unfortunately crash reports have 2 days late. And because the application crash at launch, I don't think she has time to send report.

Comment: You can try to handle UnhandledException and write the exception details to a text file. Then try to use a tool like IsoStoreSpy to access the log and see what the error is

Comment: Also, are you sure the application crashes. or just closes after being run? The second case may be as a result of the app loading slowly, and timeouting before displaying the main window. I had a similar issue in one of my apps ...

Comment: @Jogy What I don't understand is why my app work good when I install the .xap file with power tool, or by debuging the app with visual studio. The app does not work only if I download from the store.

Comment: @ejanowski No idea .. can you try to package a new version and submit it as a the beta to the store and experiment with it?

Comment: @ejanowski by the way, just installed the app and I can confirm, it crashes immediately after starting .. so it is not a timeout problem. Could it be some problem with the packaging?

Comment: @Jogy Sorry for the delay. I try severals thinks : update my app as you recommend (still crashing), checkout old commit, and submit old .xap file (still crashing). I'm pretty sure that the problem is not in my code....

Comment: @ejanowski Did you try to publish another .xap as a beta in the store?

Comment: @Jogy Not yet, I will try it ASAP

Comment: @Jogy I have submit the xap in beta on my own account (which have the old dashboard, don't know why...) And the app work fine.

Comment: @ejanowski At this point, short of contacting MS support directly, I can't think of any other idea ....

Comment: I recommend using a tool for crash analytics like https://mint.splunk.com

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same incredible problem...
**There is (at least) a bug in the WP 8.1 OS with 50 character long "Identity Name" (what is the key to update the app).**
I have described it in detail here:
[App don't start after update over the store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28325075/the-store-version-of-my-windows-phone-8-1-app-does-not-start-on-my-dev-phone/33036293#33036293)